# NetLogo: how to update "(p)label" every tick?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to track the behavior of my turtle. One of the turtles-own variable is `[energy]`. I would like to observe how this variable changes over time. If I ask

`ask turtle 0 [set label energy]`

in code or by observer, I reach just actual energy value. Using `go once` button the label stay the same, even if my energy value changes.

Please, how can I update label of [energy] value each tick? The same question for changing plabel values. Thank you !

Comment: Put the command in the go method. it will update is if there is  an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of how you can do it. I created a simple turtle which walks randomly and updates its energy level. Center patch shows energy level of turtle 0 as plabel:

```
   turtles-own [energy]
    to setup
      clear-all
      reset-ticks
      crt 1[set energy 500]

    end

    to go
      ask turtle 0[
        set label energy
        set energy energy - 1

        fd 1
        rt random 10

      ]
      ask patch 0 0 [
        set plabel [energy] of turtle 0
      ]
      tick
    end
```

Comment: thank you again @Marzy ! I was always little bit confused about meaning of syntax : set energy energy - 1 but now it is much clearer :)